# Reverse Polish Expression - Monitoring the Input

Tags: python, expression, postfix-notation

So I have the code to make the Reverse Polish Expression work

```
def rpn(x):
    stack = []
    operators=['+', '-', '*']

    for i in x.split(' '):
        if i in operators:
            op1 = stack.pop()
            op2 = stack.pop()
            if i=='+': result = op2 + op1
            if i=='-': result = op2 - op1
            if i=='*': result = op2 * op1
            stack.append(result)
        else:
            stack.append(float(i))

    return stack.pop()


x = str(input("Enter a polish expression:"))
result = rpn(x)
print (result)
```

However I'm struggling on how to provide some error messages for specific inputs
Currently this code will only work if i have a space after each value i.e.
3 4 + then ill get a result of 7

But I want to make it so that it either

-Removes the spacing automatically

or the code will only work without the spacing and provide an error if there is spacing
I thought of adding the code something along the lines of

```
if x contains " ":
   print("error")
```

My second issue that i'm trying to work around is, limiting the operators used
So it will only run the code if it has numbers and 3 operators (+,-,*) if there are any other operators or letters it will show an error. Again my thinking of it would be

```
if x contains something other than "integers and +,-,*:
     then print an error
```

Again I have the concept but not the python key word knowledge on how to perform it.

Comment: Without spaces how do you determine when one number ends? Unless every number is a single digit.

Comment: Ah i should have mentioned, indeed it will only be single digit

Comment: You can just iterator over `x.strip()` and discard spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `x.split()` instead of `x.split(' ')`, it will extract everything but the spaces from `x`.

`split()` treats multiple successive spaces as one space (so one delimiter), while `split(' ')` treats one space as one delimiter.

Here's the difference:

```
>>> print('   '.split(' '))
['', '', '', '']
>>> print('   '.split())
[]
```

Given that your code will be dealing only with single-digit numbers:

```
for i in (_ for _ in x if not _.isspace()):
    # your algorithm
```

If you'd like to raise an error:

```
for i in (_ if not _.isspace() else None for _ in x):
    if i is None:
        raise ValueError("Error!")
    # your algorithm here
```

Comment: This does make sense, but now lets say we enter as the input (34+) it will show an error because i'm trying to convert a string to float. So is removing the spacing really tackling my issue? Or does this mean the my code cannot work unless it has the spaces?

Comment: But `34+` doesn't make any sense. This is the same as `34 + WHAT??`.

Comment: Well 34+ in terms of RPM would be the same as 3 + 4

Comment: It wouldn't, but `3 4+` would. Note the space.

Comment: Well it would be 3 4+ if we aren't taking the fact that this code is for single digits, so even if it is 345++, we are suggesting it is 3 + 4 + 5

Comment: Could you possibly explain that new edit? I've never used underscores in code before

Comment: @Xrin, an underscore is just a name of a variable, nothing special here

Comment: Oh okay so a list comprehension is used. So now I can add another if statement within my function(?) that if the input contains a space, then it shows an error?

Comment: @Xrin, do you really need to show an error in this case? It's perfectly valid to separate numbers and operators with spaces.

Comment: @Xrin, BTW, this _is not_ a list comprehension, it's a _generator expression_.

Comment: Well It was the idea since the code in intended for single input only. Or If it contains a space, to not complete the calculation. But i guess the error would be easier.